# O que são atributos boleanos?

Tags: html, html5, atributos

Gostaria de saber o que são esses atributos boleanos do HTML.
e como entender essa questão de verdadeiro ou falso ?

Answer (score 3):

Antes de entender os atributos booleanos em HTML é fundamental entender como funciona a lógica booleana. Dentro da lógica booleana pode-se classificar coisas ou fenômenos como verdadeiro ou falso. Um exemplo:

- Jonas Souza é do sexo masculino? Resposta: Verdadeiro
- O número 8 é maior que o número 5? Resposta: Verdadeiro
- O Brasil é um país localizado no hemisfério norte? Resposta: Falso

Perceba que todas essas perguntas só tem duas respostas possíveis: Sim ou não. Desta forma, fazendo uma analogia, a lógica booleana seria como aquilo que a sabedoria popular chama de "8 ou 80" ou de "é ou não é".

Agora vamos ao contexto do HTML. Em HTML a presença de um atributo já é suficiente para que este seja considerado "true", assim como a sua ausencia significa que este atributo recebe o valor "false". O exemplo abaixo mostra como os atributos podem ser utilizados em HTML5:

```
<audio src="BeeGees.mp3" controls>
</audio>
```

Perceba que o atributo "controls" aparece sem o comando de atribuição, isto é, a sua presença já indica que este atributo recebe o valor "true". Caso quisesse que este atributo recebesse o valor "false", bastaria retirá-lo de dentro da tag "audio".

Desta forma, sempre que você quiser que um atributo receba valor "true", basta coloca-lo na tag, quando quiser que seja "false" basta não declará-lo.

Maiores informações: http://www.maujor.com/blog/2011/09/24/atributos-booleanos/

(O trecho de código utilizado como exemplo foi extraído deste link)